# comparar array (string) en java y mostrar unicamente los resultados no repetidos del segundo

Tags: java, array

Tengo un array viejo y quiero compararlo con un array nuevo y mostrar unicamente los elementos del array nuevo sin que esten repetidos en el array viejo.

por ejemplo:

```
arrayviejo = (casa, jardin, arbol, cochera)
arraynuevo = (casa, jardin, cesped, calle)
arraylimpio = (cesped, calle)
```

Es decir, casa y jardín se repiten y por eso no tienen que estar, y ademas, árbol y cochera son del viejo array así que tampoco.
 (utilice solo palabras para el ejemplo pero cada elemento del array es una linea de 150 caracteres aproximadamente)
 Espero se entienda...
 Gracias por leer

Comment: Creo que esto es lo que buscas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283123/3919660

Comment: Deberías añadir el código que llevas hecho hasta ahora, StackOverflow no es un sitio para que te resuelvan los deberes o la tarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doy por hecho que usas Java 8 o superior, y que tus arrays son de tipo String[].

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arrayViejo = {"uno", "dos", "tres"};
        String[] arrayNuevo = {"uno", "dos", "cuatro", "cinco"};

        List<String> listaVieja = Arrays.asList(arrayViejo);

        String[] arrayLimpio = Stream.of(arrayNuevo).filter(i->!listaVieja.contains(i)).toArray(String[]::new);

        for (int i = 0; i<arrayLimpio.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(arrayLimpio[i]);//sale cuatro cinco
        }
    }
```

Básicamente:

1. Pasar el array viejo a una lista para facilitar trabajar con él.
2. Crear un stream sobre el array nuevo, filtrar para que solo queden
   los elementos que no están en la lista vieja, pasar a un nuevo
   array.

Comment: Hola @pablo, gracias por la resuesta, funciona perfecto

Answer (score 1):

Los compañeros han dado varias soluciones posibles y todas válidas.

De todos modos, si me lo permitís, añado alguna reflexión.

1.- Hay que tener en cuenta que no es lo mismo comparar objetos que cadenas de caracteres. No es lo mismo que tengas el mismo objeto en dos arrays a tener dos objetos con la misma cadena.

En el primer caso, la comparación sería más rápida y se podría usar (hay más formas) el método equals de la **[clase Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)**

En este caso, tendrías que recorrer (en el mejor de los casos) todos los elementos del primer array. Es decir, que estamos hablando de una progresión aritmética. En estos casos una pequeña mejora sería comparar el más pequeño (menos elementos) con el más grande para evitar iteraciones innecesarias.

En el segundo caso, además de tener que recorrer todos los elementos del array, tendrías que comprobar la cadena que contiene, añadiendo más tiempo de proceso.

Es una diferencia **importante** que tienes que tener en cuenta.

En el ejemplo que pones das unos pocos elementos en cada array y no notarás apenas diferencia entre una y otra cosa, pero ¿y si tuvieras que hacer esa comprobación sobre 10000 elementos o sobre 10^6? ¿y si además tuvieras que hacer esa comprobación constantemente? Ya estaríamos hablando de un costo computacional importante.

2.- Hay que tener en cuenta el tipo de dato que se quiere guardar y las operaciones que se van a realizar sobre los mismos.

La API de colecciones de Java tiene múltiples estructuras de datos que te pueden ayudar mucho en problemas relativamente genéricos como el que planteas.

Dado el problema que propones, es posible que el array no sea la estructura más conveniente para comparar cadenas de caracteres. Si los datos de referencia van a ser relativamente estables posiblemente sea mejor una estructura ordenada. Estas estructuras tardan un poco más en almacenar los elementos pero son **definitivamente más rápidas** en las consultas. Un ejemplo son los **[TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)**

Esta estructura es ordenada y no admite duplicados, por lo que, a lo mejor, no te sirve y tendrás que utilizar otra que sí te permita tener duplicados o que te permita manejarla desde múltiples hilos de ejecución y necesite estar sincronizada... la lista de requerimientos es extensa. Pero en general es importante utilizar **una estructura de datos acorde a los datos y uso que se vaya a hacer**.

En tu caso lo que quieres hacer, grosso modo, es una **intersección de conjuntos** y para eso, lo más correcto sería que, sobre dicho TreeSet, implementaras el método retainAll o removeAll de la **[interfaz Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-)**
Esto te permitiría, sobre la estructura de Java, crear tu propio algoritmo para la intersección de conjuntos según los parámetros que tú mismo estimes necesario. Lo bueno de esto es que dicha estructura sería reutilizable en tantos programas como necesites.

Por dejarte una respuesta un poco más directa y veas un ejemplo de algo medianamente parecido, puedes utilizar un **[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)** tal y como te dicen los compañeros, en lugar de un array básico. Si te fijas en la implementación.
verás que esta clase ya implementa el método retainAll() que lo que hace es, ni más ni menos, una intersección de conjuntos.

En definitiva, para cada problema su solución.

Un saludo a todos.

Comment: Hola @Rafa, gracias por la aclaracion, me va a ser muy util ya que voy a trabajar con array de 2000 datos y cada cadena tiene mas de 500 caracteres. Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tus arrays sean de tipo ArrayList de String, te propongo la siguiente solución:

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayViejo =  new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayViejo.add("casa");
    arrayViejo.add("jardin");
    arrayViejo.add("arbol");
    arrayViejo.add("cochera");
    ArrayList<String> arrayNuevo = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayNuevo.add("casa");
    arrayNuevo.add("jardin");
    arrayNuevo.add("cesped");
    arrayNuevo.add("calle");
    ArrayList<String> arrayLimpio=crearArrayLimpio(arrayViejo,arrayNuevo);
    for(String elemento: arrayLimpio){
        System.out.println(elemento);
    }
}

public static ArrayList<String> crearArrayLimpio (ArrayList<String> arrayViejo, ArrayList<String> arrayNuevo){
    ArrayList<String> arrayLimpio= new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String elemento: arrayNuevo) {
        if (!contieneElemento(arrayViejo, elemento)) arrayLimpio.add(elemento);
    }
    return arrayLimpio;
}

public static boolean contieneElemento( ArrayList<String> array, String elemento) {
    for(String elementoArray: array) {
        if (elemento.equals(elementoArray)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Montenegro, gracias por la respuesta